# Python.Рекурсия.Двоичные числа

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
def printBin(num):
if num < 0:
    print('-', end='')
num = abs(num)
if num == 0:
    return
if num > 0:
    printBin(num // 2)
    print(num % 2, end="")
```

Если изначальное число равно 0, то в таком случае функция реторнит None.
Что надо сделать,чтоб при вводе 0 реторнился 0, используя лишь метод рекурсии, при этом не используя иных функций?

Comment: return 0 в строке где у вас return

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Дело в том, что последний вызов нужно делать для числа большего 1. А печать должна быть отложенной, после завершения рекурсивного вызова.

```
def printBin(num):
    if num < 0:
        print('-', end='')
    num=abs(num)
    if num >1:
        printBin(num // 2)
    print(num % 2, end='')
```

Answer (score 0):

```py
num = int(input())
def printBin(num):
    if num < 0:
        print('-', end='')
    num = abs(num)
    if num == 0:
        return num
    if num > 0:
        printBin(num // 2)
        print(num % 2, end="")

print(printBin(num))
```

Comment: здесь есть ошибка,вывод неправильный.

Comment: надо уж либо на консоль выводить, либо значение возвращать, а тут смесь разных подходов получается